# Can't assign necessary entries to a CVXPY (2,2) Variable

Tags: python, cvxpy

I'm trying to implement [this research paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04232).  The paper is combining multiple metrics into a single joint formulation.  The authors manipulate it into an optimization problem, with the condition of a semi-definite program.

[image]

M, N are whole numbers.  Mu, gamma, and tau are real numbers.  b is a (n, 1) vector.  A is an (n,n) matrix.  **1** is an (n,1) vector of all ones.  **I** is an (n,n) identity matrix.

This is how I'm trying to implement it with cvxpy:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

def test_cvxpy(A, b, M, N):
    if M == 0:
        return None, None
    else:
        mu, gamma, tau = cp.Variable(), cp.Variable(), cp.Variable()
        objective = cp.Maximize(mu * (2*M - N)**2 - gamma * N - tau)
        
        # the minor diagnol element of the SDP matrix
        element = np.array((b - 2*mu*(2*M - N) * np.ones_like(b)) / 2)
        # the last element of the SDP matrix
        last = A + mu * np.ones_like(A) + gamma * np.identity(len(A))
        
        SDP = np.array([[tau, element.T], [element, last]])
        
        matrix = cp.Parameter(shape=(2,2), PSD=True)
        matrix.project_and_assign(SDP)
        
        constraints = [matrix >> 0]
        prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
        prob.solve(verbose=True)

        return mu.value[0], gamma.value[0]
```

Only if I define the `matrix` to be PSD=True, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [148], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for A, b, M, df_by_class in zip(As, bs, water_units, dfs_by_class):
      2     N = len(df_by_class)
----> 3     mu, gamma = test_cvxpy(A, b, M, N)
      4     if mu is not None:
      5         x = test_solution(A, b, M, N, mu, gamma)

Input In [147], in test_cvxpy(A, b, M, N)
     13 SDP = np.array([[tau, element.T], [element, last]])
     15 matrix = cp.Variable(shape=(2,2), PSD=True)
---> 16 matrix.project_and_assign(SDP)
     18 constraints = [matrix >> 0]
     19 prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\leaf.py:371, in Leaf.project_and_assign(self, val)
    368 def project_and_assign(self, val) -> None:
    369     """Project and assign a value to the variable.
    370     """
--> 371     self.save_value(self.project(val))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\leaf.py:339, in Leaf.project(self, val)
    337 if self.attributes['symmetric']:
    338     return val
--> 339 w, V = LA.eigh(val)
    340 if self.attributes['PSD']:
    341     bad = w < 0

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in eigh(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:1470, in eigh(a, UPLO)
   1467     gufunc = _umath_linalg.eigh_up
   1469 signature = 'D->dD' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->dd'
-> 1470 w, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   1471 w = w.astype(_realType(result_t), copy=False)
   1472 vt = vt.astype(result_t, copy=False)

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'eigh_lo' input from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Removing the `PSD=True` condition, it stalls at:

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.2.0                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Your problem has 3 variables, 1 constraints, and 4 parameters.
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=SCS).
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Reduction chain: FlipObjective -> Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> SCS
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Applying reduction FlipObjective
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Apr 15 12:06:02 PM: Applying reduction SCS
```

Comment: I think they're getting erased as I edit my post and save the changes.  I thought you were deleting them.

Comment: Then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31546371).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply NumPy functions to CVXPY objects. You need to use CVXPY array construction functions like `bmat` instead of putting things inside of NumPy arrays. Here is a version of your code that works:

```
def test_cvxpy(A, b, M, N):
    if M == 0:
        return None, None
    else:
        mu, gamma, tau = cp.Variable(), cp.Variable(), cp.Variable((1, 1))
        objective = cp.Maximize(mu * (2*M - N)**2 - gamma * N - tau)

        # the minor diagnol element of the SDP matrix
        element = (b - 2*mu*(2*M - N) * np.ones_like(b)) / 2
        element = element[:, None]
        # the last element of the SDP matrix
        last = A + mu * np.ones_like(A) + gamma * np.identity(len(A))

        matrix = cp.bmat([[tau, element.T], [element, last]])


        constraints = [matrix >> 0]
        prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
        prob.solve(verbose=True)

        return mu.value[0], gamma.value[0]
```